Powershell script prevents computer idling completely
I wanted to keep my computer (W11) from idling ONLY whenever I am connecting to some of the services I host, while still keeping the 30-minute idle timer that I usually have when not connected, for it to go to sleep after that time (just sleep, hibernation is disabled completely).
The script just pings some clients from the file with their IPs and changes the time it takes to check incoming connections to specific ports, then change the system idle timer for the PC to disabled if I am connected to it and revert it when I'm not.
Thing is after making the script and all I realized the computer just doesn't idle and go to sleep when I'm not using it anymore (the sleep timer changes work, the script just keeps the computer awake anyway). At first, I thought it was the ping to my client what was preventing the idling, but apparently it's the actual file handling when loading the client IP's to ping.
So, is there any way to make this script work while letting my computer sleep as the script is checking for any connection? Or is there a better way to achieve this? I did it with PowerShell, since it's the native thing for windows. Here's the code:
#Function to load IP addresses from the clients file
function Load-Clients {
    param (
        [string]$filePath
    )
    return Get-Content -Path $filePath
}

#Load IP addresses from the clients file
$clientsFilePath = "$PSScriptRoot\..\clients"
$deviceIPs = Load-Clients -filePath $clientsFilePath

$interval = 60 # Check every 60 seconds when no connections
$shortInterval = 30 # Check every 30 seconds when the device is reachable
$longInterval = 1800 # Check every 30 minutes when connections are detected
$portsToCheck = @(8000, 7860, 5000, 5001, 80) # List of ports to check for connections
$originalTimeout = 30 # Original sleep timeout in minutes
$sleepTimerDisabled = $false

while ($true) {
     $deviceReachable = $false

     foreach ($deviceIP in $deviceIPs) {
         $pingResult = Test-Connection -ComputerName $deviceIP -Count 1 -Quiet
         if ($pingResult) {
             Write-Output "Device $deviceIP is reachable."
             $deviceReachable = $true
             break
         } else {
             Write-Output "Device $deviceIP is not reachable."
         }
     }

     if ($deviceReachable) {
         Write-Output "Device is reachable. Checking connections every 30 seconds."
         $checkInterval = $shortInterval
     } else {
         Write-Output "Device is not reachable. Checking connections every 60 seconds."
         $checkInterval = $interval
     }

    # Default to checking every 60 seconds since ping functionality is commented out
    $checkInterval = $interval

    $activity = 0

    foreach ($port in $portsToCheck) {
        $activity += (Get-NetTCPConnection -State Established | Where-Object { $_.LocalPort -eq $port }).Count
    }

    Write-Output "Connections detected: $activity"

    if ($activity -gt 0) {
        if (!$sleepTimerDisabled) {
            # Disable the sleep timer
            powercfg /change standby-timeout-ac 0
            $sleepTimerDisabled = $true
            Write-Output "Sleep timer disabled. Waiting for 30 minutes."
        }
        # Wait for 30 minutes
        Start-Sleep -Seconds $longInterval
    } else {
        if ($sleepTimerDisabled) {
            # Revert to the original sleep timer
            powercfg /change standby-timeout-ac $originalTimeout
            $sleepTimerDisabled = $false
            Write-Output "No connections detected. Sleep timer reverted to original."
        }
        Write-Output "Waiting for $checkInterval seconds."
        # Wait for the specified interval
        Start-Sleep -Seconds $checkInterval
    }
}

Thanks in advance.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. The way the question is written, it is not clear what you want to prevent. It should go to sleep but not hibernate?

Sorry, I tried to clean up the post a bit. I want PowerShell to NOT prevent the computer idling (and thus, let it go to sleep) when loading a file with it. It works when I just let it check for connections, but when I load the file it just prevents it idling completely for some reason.
